# Append is giving different results than write

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

I'm trying to convert multiple binary files into one CSV file. My code works if I use 'w' #write to a file, but each new iteration writes over the last one. However, when I use 'a' #add to a file, my resulting values are different than when I use 'w' (and incorrect). Is there a way to get my results into one file without overwriting the previous results without using append?

Here's my code:

```
import os
import numpy as np

fileLib1 = ('/path1/')
ref = ('/path2/ref.csv')

for file in os.scandir(fileLib1):
    with open(file,'rb') as f:
        text = list(np.fromfile(f,dtype=np.float32))
    with open(ref,'a') as conv:   #problem, 'a' vs 'w'
        for n in text:
            conv.write('%s,\n' %n)
```

Comment: Use `open(file, 'ab')` instead for writing binary.

Comment: 'ab' gives me the problem, 'Kernel died, restarting'. 'rb' seems to be working for me so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get why you open and close the target file at each iteration: simply **open the file with `w` at the beginning** of the program, and close it at the end:

```
import os
import numpy as np

fileLib1 = ('/path1/')
ref = ('/path2/ref.csv')

with open(ref,'w') as conv: # open the target file at the beginning
    for file in os.scandir(fileLib1):
        with open(file,'rb') as f:
            text = list(np.fromfile(f,dtype=np.float32))
        for n in text:
            conv.write('%s,\n' %n)
```

This will also probably increase the performance of the program a bit, since opening/closing/... files are usually OS operations and thus are not for free so to speak.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but arranging it like that gives me the same problem, where for some reason my resulting file has different values than it should. I don't understand why that is, but, it is.

Comment: @Appelynn: in that case it cannot be the flie mode. Are you sure it is not one of your numpy files that contains weird results. Note that originally, only the last numpy file is saved.

Comment: Turns out I had a hidden file that was messing me up, thank you for the help.